# Any tag of gcc to compile Cpp file which includes C 3rd party header file

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, g++, header-files

There is 3rd part header file (header.h) define a structure a below, it can be passed compiling when treat it as C language. But we trying to include this file in CPP file, and the compiling is failed since g++ compiling more restriction or other reason?

```
shell@hercules$ g++ main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
header.h:10: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct conn_t conn_t’
header.h:9: error: ‘struct conn_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘struct conn_t’
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8: error: aggregate ‘conn_t list’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

---

Header file header.h:

```
 1  #ifndef __HEADER_H__
 2  #define __HEADER_H__
 3  #ifdef __cplusplus
 4  extern "C" {
 5  #endif
 6  typedef struct
 7  {
 8      int data;
 9      struct conn_t *next;
10  }conn_t;
11
12  #ifdef __cplusplus
13  }
14  #endif
15
16  #endif // __HEADER_H__
```

Cpp file main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    conn_t list;
    list.data = 1;
    list.next = NULL;
    cout<<"hello:"<<list.data<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Question: Is there any tag of gcc/g++ to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
   int data;
   struct conn_t *next;
}conn_t;
```

I don't know if in some compilers what you're doing here is valid, but it seems wrong to me. If you use a typedef you shouldn't prefix the typename with `struct`. Also the name `conn_t` in this case will be defined as soon as the struct is declared but isn't valid **inside** the declaration. This way the code'll work:

```
struct conn_t
{
   int data;
   struct conn_t *next;
};
```

No typedefs, I'm just using the struct name.

Comment: There is another difference between C and C++ here. In C++ you don't need the `typedef struct conn_t conn_t;` to use the conn_t name without `struct`. It works anyway.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it shall be no header file updating since header file is 3rd party.

Comment: Yes, the definition is valid C, but in C, the field "next" does not point to to a value of type "conn_t", it points to a value of type "struct conn_t", an entirely different type.  In C, "conn_t" and "struct conn_t" can be different types.  In C++, they can not.  That is why this is an error in C++. But here, we have to treat "conn_t" and "struct conn_t" as same type.

Answer (score 1):

It should be written like this in order to have a typedef and to have a reference to the structure itself:

```
typedef struct tag_conn_t
{
   int data;
   struct tag_conn_t *next;
}conn_t;
```

Good luck,

Iulian

Comment: If this is the case you should do a C wrapper callable from C++. In the C wrapper you include the file and create functions so that you can export the functionality.

Comment: But still you can modify the header as described provided that you mention this somewhere in the header. Since the structure doesn't change size/offsets it should work.

Comment: If it's simple header file as this example show will be fine, but the fact is the header file does not include only one type definition. so the header file modifying seems not good idea I think, :p

Comment: If there is only this type of problem sure you can make a script (perl?) that can do this automatically. You search for "typedef struct {" ... STUFF ... "} NAME;" You change this to "typedef struct tag#NAME#" ... and in the STUFF you replace "struct #NAME#" with "struct tag#NAME#". This is what I would do - something automatic.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, the header file is 3rd party C header file, it can be compiled in C language;
2. Second, the header file can not be updated, just for specific purpose, I have to includes this header file in my C++ file, and then during compile the C++, the header file also will be treat as C++, that's what problem I encountered.

I still need you genius give me the answer for that, really appreciate your guys response here.

Comment: If the header is a valid C header, but an invalid C++ header, what do you do? Complain to the supplier?

Comment: I think the only option is to #include the header file in a C file, write a C interface which does whatever we need, and call that interface from C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `-x language` tag, with `c-header` for language on gcc/g++ is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I'm look for such tag, but as I use "-x c" tag, the main.cpp can not be passed the compiling since some part of main.cpp shall be treated as C++.